# Problem with FrameLabel in the ErrorListPlot function

Tags: plotting

I've been trying to print information on the axes of a graphic. I'm doing that by the option `FrameLabel` in the `ErrorListPlot` function. But it failed.

Here the code I'm using

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];

d    = Import["teste.txt", "TSV"];
dNew = Table[{{d[[i, 1]], d[[i, 2]]}, ErrorBar[d[[i, 3]]]}, {i, 2, Length[d]}];

ErrorListPlot[dNew, FrameLabel -> {"Position, x (inches)", "Photodetector output (V)"}]
```

The result

[image]

How can I fix it?

Thanks for the attention.

Hellon

Comment: Is there a way of plot the "Position, x (inches)" below the x axis and the "Photedector output(V)" next to y? –  Hellon Canella Machado

Answer (score 1):

In ErrorListPlot, there is not such an option as "FrameLable", but "AxesLable", so use "AxesLable" instead of "FrameLable", just like this
[image]

Another way to do that is using function "Show, like this:

```
 ErrorListPlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}]];
 Show[%, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Position, x (inches)", "Photodetector output (V)"}]
```

[image]

I'm sorry that my poor English is very poor, so I can not give much explain

Comment: Is there a way of plot the "Position, x (inches)" below the x axis and the "Photedector output(V)" next to y?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the answer to show the way

Comment: Thank you guy. Your suggestions were very useful. Hellon

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Frame -> True` to specify `FrameLabel`:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"] 

ErrorListPlot[{
  {{1, 1}, ErrorBar[0.2]},
  {{2, 2}, ErrorBar[0.1]},
  {{3, 4}, ErrorBar[0.3]},
  {{4, 6}, ErrorBar[0.4]}}, 
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"Position, x (inches)", "Photodetector output (V)"   },
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]